# How can I search data from tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, uisearchbardelegate

I have an `UITableview` controller which representing fetched XML data. For representing these data I used five `UILabel`. Now I have to add a `searchbar` at the top of the `UITableview`. So programmatically I have added a `searchbar`.

Now I have used searching theorem for search data from the `UITableview`. But It is not working. I can `search` data from `UItableview` when only one text in the `UItableviewcell` without any `UIlabel` or something else but in my `UItableviewcell` cell are taking five `UILabel` that's why it's becoming tough for me to `search` data from the `UItableviewcell`. For understanding I am attaching my code how I am representing my XML data in `tableview` cell.

This is my XML data representation in `UITableviewCell`...

```
 static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellView.tag =10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    imgView.tag = 5;
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

    CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
    idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
    idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    idLabel.tag = 0;

    CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
    statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    statusLabel.tag = 1;

    CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
    orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
    orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    orderDate.tag = 2;

    CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
    byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
    byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    byLabel.tag = 3;

    CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
    totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
    totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    totalLabel.tag = 4;

    [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
    [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];
}


if(searching == YES){

    //[cell setText:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else{

    cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
    statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
    orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
    byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
    totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];
    imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];
    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO){
        idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0]];
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
        orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:2]];
        byLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:3]];
        totalLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:4]];
    }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO){
        idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0]];
        statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
        orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:2]];
        byLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:3]];
        totalLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[pendingRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:4]];
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

And this searching Delegate.....

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
searching = YES;
// only show the status bar’s cancel button while in edit mode
sBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
sBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
// flush the previous search content
[tableData removeAllObjects];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
searching = NO;
sBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
[tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] && searchText==nil){
    [tableview reloadData];
    return;
}
NSInteger counter = 0;
for(NSString *name in dataSource)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText];
    if(r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
        {
            [tableData addObject:name];
        }
    }
    counter++;
    [pool release];
}
[tableview reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
// if a valid search was entered but the user wanted to cancel, bring back the main list content
[tableData removeAllObjects];
searching = NO;

[tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];
@try{
    searching = NO;
    [tableview reloadData];
}
@catch(NSException *e){
}
[sBar resignFirstResponder];
sBar.text = @"";
}

// called when Search (in our case “Done”) button pressed
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[sBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

For more help to understand i am also attaching my `viewDidLoad`....

```
//Add the search bar
sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
sBar.delegate = self;
searching = NO;
[self.view addSubview:sBar];

tableview.dataSource = self;
tableview.delegate = self;

//initialize the two arrays; datasource will be initialized and populated by appDelegate
searchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


[tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];//on launch it should display all the records
```

### Edit

This is my edited portion of `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
if(searching == YES){
    searching = NO;
    sectionCount = [tableData count];
}
else {
    if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == NO){
        sectionCount = [records count];
        NSLog(@"section cout: %d",sectionCount);
    }
    else if(pendingOrder == YES && todaysOrder == NO){

        //Total pending order counting
        sectionCount = [pendingRecords count];
        NSLog(@"section cout for pending: %d",sectionCount);
    }
    else if(pendingOrder == NO && todaysOrder == YES){      
        NSLog(@"todays order number counting");     
    }
}
return sectionCount;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

copylistofItem is NSMutableArray copying data that matched with search bar criteria.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i=0
    for (NSString *str in [records objectAtIndex:indexPath.i] objectAtIndex:0])
    {
                [searchArray addObject:str];
                i++;    
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {

        NSString *txtToSearch =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[sTemp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,[searchText length])]];


        if([[txtToSearch lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[searchText lowercaseString]])
        {
            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];     
        }

    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;

}
```

Also we want to know what you have written in your numberOfSections tableView Delegate.

Comment: if(searching == YES){

    //[cell setText:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
I think you have to change this part when the searching_done function is called reload the tableview with the copylistOfItems array.

Comment: how can i get `[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.i] objectAtIndex:0] ` in `- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
` because i need indexPath value.

Comment: Record is an 2D array you have intiated in the header file.  When searching is not done tableview is loaded from the records array when searching is done it will populate the tableview with copylistofitems array but this array will gave only index 0 row data from records array of all sections.you have to work out for all the indexes in the same way just like copylistofitems 1D array.